# Add new row with dropdown on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add new rows on button click:

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 20px 0;">
     <div id="AddContainer">
          <!--new rows with content to add will be added here-->
     </div>
     <br />
     <input id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="+" />
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
var div = $("<div />");
div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(''));
$("#AddContainer").append(div);
});

$("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
    var values = "";
    $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
        values += $(this).val() + "\n";
    });
    alert(values);
});

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
    var ddlId = $('[id*=hfDDLId]').val();
    $('[id$=ddl' + parseInt(ddlId) + ']').remove();
    $('[id*=hfDDLId]').val(parseInt($('[id*=hfDDLId]').val()) - 1);
    var previousDropDownId = $('[id*=hfDropDownIds]').val();
    $('[id*=hfdropdownids]').val(resultids);
    //}
});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    var combo = $("<select></select>").attr("id", value).attr("name", value).attr("runat", "server").attr("class", "class").attr("required", "required");
    $.each(document.pvm.SettingsList(), function (i, el) {
        combo.append("<option value=" + el + ">" + el + "</option>");
    });
    return '<input type="button" value="-" class="remove btn btn-danger" />&nbsp'
    + combo + '&nbsp'
    + '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="' + value + '" required/>&nbsp'
}

function ClearAddTab() {
    document.getElementById("AddContainer").innerHTML = "";
}
```

and the settings list is:

```
_mVM.SettingsList = ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']);
```

The problem is that I want need to add the dropdown with the `SettingsList` options for each new added row, but it displays [object object].
It is possible to add the dropdown between the red button and the text field, but also to allow the user to delete that row by pressing the red button?

Comment: What is `_mVM.SettingsList`? Where is that coming from?

Comment: When running function GetDynamicTextBox it looks like you might want the html of the combo variable rather than the element object itself.  Try combo.prop('outerHTML') when returning the string and you should get the dropdown html rather than [object object].  JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fgazfLaz/

Comment: @Scott Marcus, the list will come from the database. For now I've added it just as an example

Comment: @Alec Menconi - I've tried your JsFiddle and it worked! Can you add it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you want the HTML of the selected DOM object rather than the object itself.

When running function GetDynamicTextBox try combo.prop('outerHTML') when returning the string and you should get the dropdown html rather than [object object].

JsFiddle: jsfiddle.net/fgazfLaz

HTML

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 20px 0;">
  <div id="AddContainer">
      <!--new rows with content to add will be added here-->
  </div>
  <br />
  <input id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="+" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var settingsListAry = ['France', 'Germany', 'Spain'];

$("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
    //var test = GetDynamicTextBox('a');
    //alert("test");
    var div = $("<div />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(''));
    $("#AddContainer").append(div);
});

$("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
    var values = "";
    $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
        values += $(this).val() + "\n";
    });
    alert(values);
});

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
    var ddlId = $('[id*=hfDDLId]').val();
    $('[id$=ddl' + parseInt(ddlId) + ']').remove();
    $('[id*=hfDDLId]').val(parseInt($('[id*=hfDDLId]').val()) - 1);
    var previousDropDownId = $('[id*=hfDropDownIds]').val();
    $('[id*=hfdropdownids]').val(resultids);
    //}
});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {

    var combo = $("<select></select>").attr("id", value).attr("name",     value).attr("runat", "server").attr("class", "class").attr("required", "required");

    $.each(settingsListAry, function (i, el) {
        combo.append("<option value=" + el + ">" + el + "</option>");
    });

    return '<input type="button" value="-" class="remove btn btn-danger" />&nbsp'
    + combo.prop('outerHTML') + '&nbsp'
    + '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="' + value + '" required/>&nbsp'
}

function ClearAddTab() {
    document.getElementById("AddContainer").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a `<div>` inside `<div id="AddContainer">` this will hold for appending a new input.

```
<div id="AddContainer">
          <!--new rows with content to add will be added here-->
          <div></div>
     </div>
```

Add an onclick event on your button then call this function, it will append a new button:

```
<script>
   function addButton()
   {
      $('#AddContainer')
      .find('div')
      .remove()
      .end()
      .append('<input type="button" value="button"
      /><div></div>');
   }
</script>
```

Your input button:

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" onclick="addButton();" class="btn btn-success" value="+" />
```